# 10,25,50,100,250,500,1000 how to find this sequence equation to plot in a graph

Tags: math, numbers, number-formatting, equation-solving

10,25,50,100,250,500,1000..... How to find above number series equation.

I need to generate the number pattern like above to plot it in my graph.

I tried like 2x, 2x, 2x + x / 2, 2x, 2x, ..... 2n, but I am unable to find a correct format of the equation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It's about math.

Comment: This is just set of "nice-looking" values for axes tick labels to plot charts. `10,25,50 * 10^k`

Comment: @MBo or the typical scales on an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an expression in computer code (Python, to be precise). Here, `n` is the position of the number in your sequence, staring with `1`. The result of this expression is the `n`th value in your sequence.

```
10 ** ((n+4)//3) * 2 ** ((n+4)%3) // 4
```

As you can see by the `// 3` and `% 3` in that expression, this works by dividing your sequence into groups of three: `25, 50, 100`, `250, 500, 1000`, etc. My expression calculates the last value in that group of three, which is a power of `10`. Then my expression multiplies by an appropriate fractional factor, one of `1/4, 2/4, 4/4`. That multiplication by a fraction is done by multiplying by the numerator, which is a power of `2`, then dividing by `4`.

Note that `n+4` is used twice. Many programming languages, including Python, have the `divmod` function that does the `//` (integer division) and `%` (integer modulus) operations simultaneously. If you are using a function to calculate, using `divmod` could make the function easier to understand and perhaps slightly faster. Also note that I chose this expression since it is fairly easy to translate to other computing environments. If your environment does not have the `//` or `%` operation those can be done with the `int` or `trunc` or similar function. Ask if you need help translating my expression to another environment.

Printing the first 12 values of that sequence (`n` is `1` through `12`) results in

```
10
25
50
100
250
500
1000
2500
5000
10000
25000
50000
```

Comment: You can use also bitshift like this `4 >> (n % 3)` for the second part

Comment: @MBo: If you change that to `4 >> ((n+1) % 3)` that works! Great work! I don't mind if you put that in your own answer. I have thought of another way to avoid negative numbers and will now add that to my answer.

Comment: No, I wasn't going to make an answer, yours is comprehensive